# "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" when attempting to create table in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

The following is my basic create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "TESTTABLE" ( "Sub Continent" CLOB,"Continent" CLOB,"Date" DATE,"Members" NUMBER );
```

Here is the C# code:

```
OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
myConnection.Open();
if (myConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open){
  OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand(sql_command, myConnection);
  OracleDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
  myCommand.Dispose();
  myReader.Dispose();
}
myConnection.Close();
```

This produces the following error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

I know the connection string is good, I have done select statements and GetSchema calls.  I am able to copy paste the above query into SQL Developer and it runs successfully.  I am currently running Oracle 12c.  And I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: _Please_ don't use cased columns, it means you need to get it _exactly_ right each time. Pick a name, without spaces or cases etc and remove the double quotes.

Comment: Try `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteReader` since you're not returning anything.  Also post your _exact_ C# code that creates the SQL statement - double quotes can be tricky to get right inside strings.

Comment: @Ben I cannot do that, as they columns are generated programmatically from a 3rd party source. They have the potential to contain both spaces and other invalid characters.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks for the suggestion, but the same result when using ExecuteNonQuery.  With regard to posting the exact code, that is not possible.  As implied from my above comment sql_command is generated programatically.  However I have copy pasted exactly what sql_command contains by examining the variable in Debug Mode.  I am also writing that line to a file (for debug purposes) elsewhere in the code and both look identical to what was posted.